# How to turn on MySQL Server in Windows 8

Tags: mysql, iis-7

I installed MySQL 5.6.21 in Windows 8.1.

I was unable to turn on the server after turning on my Laptop.

I used a XAMP previously. Now, I am using IIS. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open

Control Panel>All Control Panel Items>Administrative Tools>Services

Right Click on MySQL & Select Enable..

(optional) Open properties & can choose Automatic..